# LuaLatex and intersection segments: Error only with Lua

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex, shell-escape, intersections

I need to use LuaLatex with my document and somehow run into an error while compiling a plot. I reduced my document to the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {
                f(\x) = \x;
            },
    ]
    % Set the circle dimensions
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xc{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yc{0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ri{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ro{3}

    \begin{axis}[
            ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
            xmin=-3, xmax=5,
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = {\textbf{Re}\((z)\)},
            ylabel = {\textbf{Im}\((z)\)},
            major grid style = {lightgray},
            width = .9\textwidth,
            scale mode=scale uniformly,
        ]
        % Draw the circles and the line
        \draw [name path=outerCircle] (\xc,\yc) circle (\ro);
        \draw [name path=innerCircle] (\xc,\yc) circle (\ri);
        \addplot[domain=0:5, name path=f] {f(x)};

        % Add the labels
        \node [anchor=north west] at (4,{f(4)}) {\(\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}\)};
        \node [anchor=north west] at (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax} - 1) {\(\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}\)};

        % Add a path along the y axis of the plot
        \path[name path=yAxis] (0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
        (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});

        % Add the intersection between inner circle and line
        \draw [
            name path=lower,
            draw=none,
            intersection segments={
                    of=innerCircle and f,
                    sequence={L2[reverse] -- R3},
                },
        ];

        % Add the intersection between inner circle + line and the outer circle
        \draw [
            name path=rightSide,
            draw=none,
            intersection segments={
                    of=outerCircle and lower,
                    sequence={R1 -- L2},
                },
        ];

        % Add the intersection between inner circle + line + outer circle and the y axis
        \draw [
            name path=full,
            draw=none,
            thick,
            intersection segments={
                    of=rightSide and yAxis,
                    sequence={R2 -- L2},
                },
        ];

        % Fill in the horizontal gray lines to mark the area
        \addplot[pattern=horizontal lines, semitransparent] fill between[of=yAxis and full];

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How it should look:

[image: Output of the PGF Plot]

When i compile it with:

```
latexmk -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=build <file.tex>
```

I get no error and the shown plot is produced (the recipe of the Latex Workshop VSCode extension).

But if i compile it with

```
latexmk -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -lualatex -outdir=build <file.tex>
```

it gives me the following error `Package pgf Error: There is no intersection segment '2' in path '2'` at the line of the `\end{axis}`.
Running the command with  only the lualatex, outdir and shell-escape options produces the same error.

Does anyone know, what the problem here is? Thanks in advance

Comment: why use shell escape here? You should not expect people to run code randomly copied off the internet with shell-escape enabled.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This code doesn't need the shell escape, but i left it in for completeness since the whole document the code came from needs the shell-escape.

Comment: honestly you should only include shell-escape in public examples if really necessary, and then highlight in large bold text that people would need to run that. personally I wouldn't run any examples from the internet with shell escape unless it was clear that I  understood every line of code posted _before_ running it. Asking people to run `latexmk -shell-escape` is asking people to trust you not to delete all their files, or email their ssh keys to you or anything else that tex code running under shell-escape could do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code is compiled with LuaLaTeX then the intersection point at the origin is not found. This is probably due to rounding errors. If the domain in the line `\addplot[domain=0:5, name path=f] {f(x)};` is changed to `domain=-0.0001:5` then the code compiles with LuaLaTeX. But it does not with `domain=-0.00001:5`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem